# Makefile not pulling in include dependency

Tags: makefile, cygwin, mingw

Here's the directory structure for my setup:

```
Matrix
│   Makefile
│
├───bin
├───include
│       matrix.h
│
├───lib
├───obj
├───rc
│       matrix.rc
│
└───src
        matrix.c
        matrix_mem.c
```

Here's the Makefile:

```
# This Makefile will build the Matrix Library.

TOOLCHAIN :=    C:\MinGW
SRCTREE :=  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Matrix\Matrix

CC :=       $(TOOLCHAIN)\bin\gcc.exe
AR :=       $(TOOLCHAIN)\bin\ar.exe
WINDRES :=  $(TOOLCHAIN)\bin\windres.exe

SRCDIR :=   $(SRCTREE)\SRC
OUTDIR :=   $(SRCTREE)\BIN
OBJDIR :=   $(SRCTREE)\OBJ
RESDIR :=   $(SRCTREE)\RC
LIBDIR :=   $(SRCTREE)\LIB
INCDIR :=   $(SRCTREE)\INCLUDE

CFLAGS :=   -O3 -std=gnu89 -Wall
CFLAGS_EXTRA :=

OBJS := $(shell find $(OBJDIR) -name '*.o')
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)
-include $(DEPS)

all: dll

dll: CFLAGS_EXTRA := -DMATRIX_USE_DLL -DDLL_EXPORTS
dll: matrix.dll

static: CFLAGS_EXTRA :=
static: matrix.lib

matrix.dll: matrix_mem.o matrix.o resource.o

matrix.lib: matrix_mem.o matrix.o

%.o: $(SRCDIR)\%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCDIR) $(CFLAGS_EXTRA) -MM -MT $(OBJDIR)\$@ -MF $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(OBJDIR)\$@) $<
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCDIR) $(CFLAGS_EXTRA) -o $(OBJDIR)\$@ $<
    @echo ...$(OBJS)...

%.dll: 
    $(CC) -shared -s -o $(OUTDIR)\$@ $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)\\%,$^) -Wl,--subsystem,windows,--output-def,$(OUTDIR)\$*.def,--out-implib,$(OUTDIR)\$*.lib

%.lib: 
    $(AR) -ru $(OUTDIR)\$@ $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)\\%,$^)

resource.o: $(RESDIR)\matrix.rc
    $(WINDRES) -i $< -o $(OBJDIR)\$@

clean::
    -rm $(OBJDIR)\matrix.o
    -rm $(OBJDIR)\matrix_mem.o
    -rm $(OBJDIR)\matrix.d
    -rm $(OBJDIR)\matrix_mem.d
    -rm $(OBJDIR)\resource.o
    -rm $(OUTDIR)\matrix.def
    -rm $(OUTDIR)\matrix.lib
    -rm $(OUTDIR)\matrix.dll
```

The `Makefile` works ok under `MinGW` and `Cygwin`.
I'm still having difficulties in getting the include dependency to work.
It appears that the `.d` files are not getting included. Since the code compiles fine across `GCC` variants, I was wanting to try to compile it on `Linux`. I want to make minimum changes to the `Makefile`.
I understand that I'll have to change the path styles and other compile options.
But, as of here, how can I get `make` to treat include dependencies correctly, without much intertwining with the shell? I'm using `make 3.80` version.
Here's a minimal source implementation:

**matrix.h:**

```
/*----------------------------- matrix.h ------------------------------*/
#ifndef __MATRIX_H_INCLUDED__
#define __MATRIX_H_INCLUDED__

#ifdef _WIN32
    #ifdef MATRIX_USE_DLL
        #ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
            #define MATRIX_API __declspec(dllexport)
        #else
            #define MATRIX_API __declspec(dllimport)
        #endif
    #else
        #define MATRIX_API
    #endif

    #define MATRIX_CALL __stdcall
#else
    #define MATRIX_API
    #define MATRIX_CALL
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct _Matrix {
    double **data;
    int m;
    int n;
} Matrix;

MATRIX_API void MATRIX_CALL dummy_func2();
MATRIX_API void MATRIX_CALL dummy_func2();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

**matrix.c:**

```
/*----------------------------- matrix.c ------------------------------*/
#include "matrix.h"

MATRIX_API void MATRIX_CALL dummy_func1() {
    return;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

**matrix_mem.c:**

```
/*--------------------------- matrix_mem.c ----------------------------*/
#include "matrix.h"

MATRIX_API void MATRIX_CALL dummy_func2() {
    return;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Can you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I understand you're probably asking for source files. I've edited the original question to include minimal source implementation. When organized in the proposed directory structure, you can reproduce the situation.

Comment: You can probably skip the resource-file compilation. I'm not including it for the sake of verbosity. You can delete the corresponding lines in Makefile.